# Collision of object with player

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I have a bit of an issue with some unity scrip. I have a moving object, a ceiling to be specific, and I have it lower and 'crush' the player. However, it's not working. The ceiling moves, but nothing happens when it collides with the player. It used to work if the player was moving when it hit them but it isn't any more and I haven't changed any of the script so I don't know why that's happening.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting suggestion from your teacher. I would put a character controller on your player, which you seem to have already. Then I would add the collision code:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c)
{
   // die.
}
```

Then add a box Collider and Rigibody to the roof. I would also add this code above to the roof.

Comment: I've tried using rigidbody in the past and it always messes everything up. He also suggested that, but when I applied the rigidbody it sort of wobbled around and refused to work with any of the other script that I had.

Comment: That might be due to the way you move the roof. Post code if you want more precise help.

Comment: It wobbled around before the script even ran. I'm not very proud of the way I made it move, as I brute forced the code and manually repositioned it multiple times so it would descend.

Comment: Tried it again with the rigid body. It caused the script (of what happenes when the wall crushes the player) to automatically run constantly to the point where I was forced to CAD the program to get it to stop as the program couldn't respond.

Comment: ++ but I would let the ceiling just fall with a rigidbody and collider but I would attach a script to Player to detect the collisions.